# Multicol: why do columns not align properly?

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

The following code does not align the contents of the two columns do not align properly; in particular, the content of the left column is a bit lower on the page than the content of the right column.

```
\documentclass [11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\noindent
So why do the two colums not align vertically?
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{align*}
& \text{\underline{function} } f_a(x): \\
& \quad \text{\underline{begin}} \\
& \quad \quad i \leftarrow 1; \\
& \quad \quad \text{\underline{while}} (g(i) \neq x) \text{ \underline{do} }         i \leftarrow i +1; \\
& \quad \quad f_a \leftarrow 0; \\
& \quad \text{\underline{end}}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
& \text{\underline{function} } f_a(x): \\
& \quad \text{\underline{begin}} \\
& \quad \quad i \leftarrow 1; \\
& \quad \quad \text{\underline{while}} (g(i) \neq x) \text{ \underline{do} }     i \leftarrow i +1; \\
& \quad \quad f_a \leftarrow 0; \\
& \quad \text{\underline{end}}
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Why? And how can I fix this?

Note: I tried using `\Columnbreak`, to no avail. Curiously, if I add a blank line between the two `align*` environments, the content of the right column is a bit lower than the one on the left...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are now. You forgot to insert the `\noindent` right before the first `align` or insert a blank line on the second `align`

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\noindent    
So why do the two colums not align vertically?
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent    %<---- here
\begin{align*}
& \text{\underline{function} } f_a(x): \\
& \quad \text{\underline{begin}} \\
& \quad \quad i \leftarrow 1; \\
& \quad \quad \text{\underline{while}} (g(i) \neq x) \text{ \underline{do} }         i \leftarrow i +1; \\
& \quad \quad f_a \leftarrow 0; \\
& \quad \text{\underline{end}}
\end{align*}   % Or enter a blank line here
\begin{align*}
& \text{\underline{function} } f_a(x): \\
& \quad \text{\underline{begin}} \\
& \quad \quad i \leftarrow 1; \\
& \quad \quad \text{\underline{while}} (g(i) \neq x) \text{ \underline{do} }     i \leftarrow i +1; \\
& \quad \quad f_a \leftarrow 0; \\
& \quad \text{\underline{end}}
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had no idea about this...

Comment: Glad it helps, we all leaned from example like this.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks for saving me from a headache. What I found interesting is that I was getting misalignment despite having globally set paragraph indents to 0pt (`\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` in the preamble). Does `\noindent` get redefined or something inside of `multicols`?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need `multicol`:

```
\documentclass [11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
So why do the two colums not align vertically?
\begin{center}
\hfill
$\!\begin{aligned}[t]
& \text{\underline{function} } f_a(x): \\
& \quad \text{\underline{begin}} \\
& \quad \quad i \leftarrow 1; \\
& \quad \quad \text{\underline{while}} (g(i) \neq x) \text{ \underline{do} }         i \leftarrow i +1; \\
& \quad \quad f_a \leftarrow 0; \\
& \quad \text{\underline{end}}
\end{aligned}$\hfill\hfill
$\!\begin{aligned}[t]
& \text{\underline{function} } f_a(x): \\
& \quad \text{\underline{begin}} \\
& \quad \quad i \leftarrow 1; \\
& \quad \quad \text{\underline{while}} (g(i) \neq x) \text{ \underline{do} }     i \leftarrow i +1; \\
& \quad \quad f_a \leftarrow 0; \\
& \quad \text{\underline{end}}
\end{aligned}$\hfill
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Are you really sure about underlining?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I think that @Jessi's answer is more readable. Ad underlining: yes, because I need to follow the notation used in the lecture.

Comment: @mort This one could come handy when the two pseudocodes have different heights.