# Align does not align equation vertically correct

Tags: formatting, align

I try to align two equations running the Lucas-Lehmer-Test side by side. I tried using

```tex
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{align*}
S_{I}(1)&=4\\
S_{I}(2)&=\left(14^{2}-2\right) mod 127 = 14\\
S_{I}(3)&=\left(67^{2}-2\right) mod 127 = 67\\
S_{I}(4)&=\left(42^{2}-2\right) mod 127 = 42\\
S_{I}(5)&=\left(111^{2}-2\right) mod 127 = 111\\
S_{I}(6)&=\left(0^{2}-2\right) mod 127 = 0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
S_{II}(1)&=4\\
S_{II}(2)&=\left(14^{2}-2\right) mod 255 = 14\\
S_{II}(3)&=\left(194^{2}-2\right) mod 255 = 194\\
S_{II}(4)&=\left(149^{2}-2\right) mod 255 = 149\\
S_{II}(5)&=\left(14^{2}-2\right) mod 255 = 14\\
S_{II}(6)&=\left(194^{2}-2\right) mod 255 = 194\\
S_{II}(7)&=\left(149^{2}-2\right) mod 255 = 149
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}
```

However it results in [image]

How can I achieve that S_I(1) and S_II(1) start at the same height? Using `minipage` results in

```tex
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
S_{I}(1)&=4\\
S_{I}(2)&=\left(14^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 14\\
S_{I}(3)&=\left(67^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 67\\
S_{I}(4)&=\left(42^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 42\\
S_{I}(5)&=\left(111^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 111\\
S_{I}(6)&=\left(0^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 0
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
S_{II}(1)&=4\\
S_{II}(2)&=\left(14^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 14\\
S_{II}(3)&=\left(194^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 194\\
S_{II}(4)&=\left(149^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 149\\
S_{II}(5)&=\left(14^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 14\\
S_{II}(6)&=\left(194^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 194\\
S_{II}(7)&=\left(149^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 149
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: never use math italic for words use `\bmod` to get `mod`

Comment: use two `\begin{minipage}[t]` not `multicols` here

Comment: .. or set it as a single align (but that means inputting the equatins row by row, not column by column)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have now updated the question - My minipages don't appear centered

Comment: you haven't privided a usable example I would have expected them to come one above the other as you have paragraph indentation to the left and a space between them sp they do not fit on a line, use \noindent before the first and `%` after the \end{minipage)` (but don't put answers into the question)

Comment: You could insert `\noindent` immediately before the first `align*` environment.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183951/47927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows the single `align` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
S_{I}(1)&=4 & S_{II}(1)&=4\\
S_{I}(2)&=\left(14^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 14 &
S_{II}(2)&=\left(14^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 14\\
S_{I}(3)&=\left(67^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 67 &
S_{II}(3)&=\left(194^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 194\\
S_{I}(4)&=\left(42^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 42 &
S_{II}(4)&=\left(149^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 149\\
S_{I}(5)&=\left(111^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 111 &
S_{II}(5)&=\left(14^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 14\\
S_{I}(6)&=\left(0^{2}-2\right) \bmod 127 = 0 &
S_{II}(6)&=\left(194^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 194\\
&& S_{II}(7)&=\left(149^{2}-2\right) \bmod 255 = 149
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]