# Align eqnarray elements in multicols

Tags: multicol, alignment, eqnarray

I want to align the elements of an eqnarrray between 2 columns.

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color,amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{eqnarray*}
        f'(x)&=&\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{5x^2}{x}\right]\\
        f'(x)&=&\frac{\dfrac{d}{dx}8x}{\dfrac{d}{dx}8x}\\
        f'(x)&=&\frac{\dfrac{d}{dx}9x^2}{\dfrac{d}{dx}x^2}\\
        f'(x)&=&\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x-5}{x^2-25}\right]
        \end{eqnarray*}
        
        \color{red}\begin{eqnarray*}
        f'(x)&=&5\\
        f'(x)&=&1\\         
        f'(x)&=&9\\
        f'(x)&=&-\frac{1}{(x+5)^2}
        \end{eqnarray*}
    \end{multicols}
```

In context, the elements of the first column are examples and the elements of the second one are the answers of those examples. But they´re not vertically aligned

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588056/align-does-not-align-equation-vertically-correct answer your question?

Comment: No, it doesn´t work

Comment: @KEIICHIROOSUNA - Sorry, but "it doesn't work" is not specific enough. *What* isn't working? What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the answer of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588056/align-does-not-align-equation-vertically-correct) the alignment works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        f'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{5x^2}{x}\right] & 
        \color{red}f'(x)&\color{red}=5\\
        f'(x)&=\frac{\dfrac{d}{dx}8x}{\dfrac{d}{dx}8x} &
        \color{red}f'(x)&\color{red}=1\\
        f'(x)&=\frac{\dfrac{d}{dx}9x^2}{\dfrac{d}{dx}x^2} &
        \color{red}f'(x)&\color{red}=9\\
        f'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x-5}{x^2-25}\right] &
        \color{red}f'(x)&\color{red}=-\frac{1}{(x+5)^2}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! Worked perfectly.

I´m going to start using \aling instead of \eqnarray

Comment: Please change all instances of `=&` to `&=`, in order to fix the faulty spacing around the `=` symbols -- as well as, in the tenth and final case, the spacing around the `-` (minus) symbol. (In your answer, the `-` symbols is incorrectly treated as a binary rather than as a unary operator. And, please delete the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` directives: `align*` environments are centered horizontally *automatically*.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your comments. I corrected the answer according to your suggestions.